# Xdebug doesn't work with PhpStorm on OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, macos, phpstorm, xdebug

I have done the following steps in order to enable xdebug with PhpStorm:

1) Paste the `phpinfo()` to https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and get the proper xdebug version to my system which is xdebug-2.5.0.tgz (php version is 5.6.27)

2) Install xdebug by running `brew install homebrew/php/php56-xdebug`

3) Edit the php.ini that located by `phpinfo()`, I add the following lines

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.27_4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_log="/usr/local/var/log/xdebug.log" 
xdebug.remote_host=xxxx.com
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

4) PhpStorm can recognize xdebug, but there are some errors below there

[image]

5) Try to do web server debug validation, get

[image]

So what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Your first screenshot shows (bottom part) that you have problems with loading extensions (including xdebug (another one?)). 1) First get rid of them -- make sure that this area of the scree has no warnings. 2) Notice the additional `.ini` config files that were loaded -- check them *they may contain those broken references etc) 3) `xdebug.remote_host=xxxx.com` -- that's wrong -- this should be an IP of the computer where debug client (PhpStorm in your case) is running. For the same computer `127.0.0.1` will do the job just fine.

Comment: 4) How do you run php? is that **php-fpm**? If so -- please also change xdebug port (in both php.ini and PhpStorm settings) to another value (e.g. `9001` or so) as php-fpm by default uses teh same TCP 9000 port which prevents xdebug from communicating with IDE.